# How can I parallelize transmission and reception of UDP packets in an object

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, networking, network-programming

What I have to do is a class  which basically has 3 methods :

- send(message, dst) which keeps sending messages (and maybe add delay with a sleep(t) and an increasing t) to dst until receiving an ACK.
- listen() which receives messages and delivers ACKs. If the message is an ACK, destroys the thread who sent the msg acquitted.
- shutdown() which stops every communication (every thread) and writes a log.

For the ACK mechanism, I thought of tables :

- host_map[port][ipadress][id] // Also used for other things which require (port,adress) =>id mapping and also because all host have ids.
- ACK[id][message][thread_to_stop] // Will be used to destroy threads except I didn't know how to put infos about the thread here and don't know where to put a join() if I even have to
- A vector of threads (or threads id, idk) to stop all the threads when I call shutdown().

I want send() and listen() to be parallelized. In other words, listen() should not block the program so it should be in a thread. Also it needs to keep receiving stuff so it would need a while loop.

In my main.cpp :

```
A link = A(my_ip,port);
A.listen();
for (int i, i < 5, i++)
  link.send(to_string(i), dst_ip, dst_port);
```

This should is supposed to make 5 threads which have while loop where they send `i` and then sleep a little, repeat until I receive an ACK.

I am new to C++ and never did multi-threading before so I don't even know if I can do this and don't even know where to put my join() if there is any.

Another thing that I thought and don't know if it's possible is to have a queue inside my class Link which keeps sending stuff and have send(msg) just adding it to the queue.

Here is something I made in A.hpp.

```
void sendm(std::string m, in_addr_t dst_ip, unsigned short dst_port){
    int id = resolveId(dst_port, dst_ip);
    int seq_number = resolveSeq(); // TODO
    std::thread th= (&A::sendMessage, this, m, dst_ip, dst_port);
    // I need something to be able to add th or an ID in my ACK table and thread vector.
    th.join();
}
void sendMessage(std::string m, in_addr_t dst_ip, unsigned short dst_port){
    //dst
            
    struct in_addr dst_ipt;
    struct sockaddr_in dst;

    dst_ipt.s_addr = dst_ip;
    dst.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dst.sin_port = htons(dst_port);
    dst.sin_addr = dst_ipt;
    
    int t = 50;

    while(true){
        std::cout << "send message m = " << m << "\n";
        //Sends a message to dst_ip through dst_port and increments the number of messages sent.
        if (sendto(obj_socket, m.c_str(), m.size(), 0,  reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr*>(&dst), sizeof(dst)) < 0){
            std::cerr << " Error sendto\n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        };
        std::cout<< "message sent\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(t));
        t+=10;
    }
}
void receive(){
    char buffer[1500];
    sockaddr_in from;
    socklen_t fromlen = sizeof(from);
    ssize_t tmp = recvfrom(obj_socket, buffer, 1500, 0, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&from), &fromlen);
    if (tmp < 0){
        std::cout << "Exit\n";
        std::cerr << "Error receive from\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else{
        if (tmp >= 0){
            
            int id = resolveId(from.sin_port, from.sin_addr.s_addr); 
            if (!verifySomething(m,id)){
                doSomethingCool(m,id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My listen() would just be a threaded version of while(true)receive();
Idk if this version compiles to be honest. I keep changing it every 2 minutes. Without the while loop in the send() and the threading, it works so far.

I didn't really implement the ACK mechanism yet.

Thank you for reading and for your help.

Comment: Putting the join immediately after creating the thread stops the creating thread until the created thread finishes. Only one thread can run at a time, so you're right back to serial code. Since you can't return from the function without the `thread` going out of scope, likely before the thread finishes executing and causing the program to terminate, you have a bit of a problem. The naïve solution is `detach`ing rather than `join`ing, but that often causes more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: What you're looking for is most likely a [thread pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool). You queue the job to the pool, and when a thread is available the pool assigns it to the thread. You do not have to join or detach or manage the thread in any way. The pool handles everything. Create the pool early on in the program at a very wide scope like `main` and you should have no problems. Unless some the threads hang. That's a nuisance.

Comment: My class has to be used in some other kind of class which is why I want the thread pool in my class. I'll try to implement it thank you for the hint

Comment: If you have [Boost](https://www.boost.org/) available, or are willing to do a bit of work to make it available, it has a [good pool implementation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/thread_pool.html) you can use.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'll try everything you said

Comment: I used a flag to stop the programs along with a thread vector. When I receive an ACK, I find the thread, turn my flag to true to stop the execution then join I join the thread. So far everything seems to work. I would like to know if there is a possible number of threads limit.

Comment: There will be, but it'll either be set by the operating system or your computer running out of some other resource like memory. In the old days you'd run out of memory first, but with a 64 bit address space that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Practically you don't want to greatly exceed the number of threads the hardware supports unless you expect those threads will be mostly idle. If they are not idle, you'll find the computer is spending more time swapping threads in and out of the CPU cores, trying to give each thread a chance at processor time, than it spends doing real work. That's one of the biggest reasons thread pools are attractive: It limits the number of active threads to something easily manageable.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll consider that to improve my program

Comment: What operation system is this code running on. If you work on Linux, you should consider using poll and similar. Basically this allows you to get notified about several sockets at once, so you don't really need a new thread for listening. This "design pattern" is more common for network code on Linux.